# Play the Chaos Game

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output, random, fractal

The [Chaos Game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_game) is a simple method to generate fractals. Given a starting point, a length ratio *r* and a set of 2D points, repeatedly do the following:

- From your set of points, pick one at random (uniformly).
- Average that point and the last drawn point (or the starting point) using *r* and *1 - r* as the weights (i.e. *r = 0* means you get the starting point, *r = 1* means you get the random point and *r = 0.5* means you get the point halfway in between.)
- Draw the resultant point.

For instance, if you picked the vertices of an equilateral triangle and *r = 0.5*, the plotted points would map out a Sierpinski triangle:

[image]

<sup>[Image found on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_game#mediaviewer/File:Sierpinski_chaos_animated.gif)</sup>

You're to write a program or function which "plays" the chaos game to create a fractal.

### Input

You may write either a program or a function, and take following inputs via ARGV, STDIN or function argument:

- The number of points to plot.
- The starting coordinate (which has to be plotted, too!).
- The averaging weight *r* in the interval *[0,1]*.
- A list of points to choose from.

### Output

You may render on screen or write an image file. If the result is rasterised, it needs to be at least 600 pixels on each side, all points must be on the canvas, and at least 75% of the horizontal and vertical extent of the image must be used for points (this is to avoid answers with a single black pixels saying "it's really far zoomed out"). The *x* and *y* axis must be on the same scale (that is the line from (0,0) to (1,1) must be at a 45 degree angle) and each point plotted in the chaos game must be represented as a single pixel (if your plotting method anti-aliases the point, it may be spread over 2x2 pixels).

Colours are your choice, but you need at least two distinguishable colours: one for the background and one for the dots plotted during the chaos game. You may but don't have to plot the input points.

Please include *three* interesting example outputs in your answer.

### Scoring

This is code golf, so the shortest answer (in bytes) wins.

**Edit:** You no longer need to plot the input points, as they aren't really visible as single pixels anyway.

Comment: What does "*each point plotted ... must be represented as a single pixel*" mean? Is it a) that no anti-aliasing should be used; or b) that the number of points in the second colour must be equal to the first item from the input? Note that b) is impossible to guarantee unless the iteration procedure has a test for "Does this pixel coincide with a previously plotted one?", because if the random number selector selects the same point enough times in a row then the position will converge to that point.

Comment: @PeterTaylor It was intended to avoid people plotting large dots as the points (like Mathematica does by default), but I've already noticed that anti-aliasing causes some trouble with ensuring single pixels in Soham's answer. I think I'll relax this to "must not be larger than 2x2 pixels", which should cover all the anti-aliasing trouble.

Comment: I think I misunderstood something: You do always take the 'mean' of the last point you plotted and a random point of the current list. Then you add that new point to the list. Is that correct? It seems that if you have many points in one 'corner' you will get many more there but it is unlikely to get out of that cloud - at least my code always 'converges' pretty fast to points that are too close to each other to really enhance the picture.

Comment: @flawr no, you don't add the new point to the list. The list is fixed - the algorithm only cares about the last point that was plotted, not the ones before it.

Comment: Thanks, that explains a lot, should perhaps be clarified in the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Mathematica, 89

```
f[n_,s_,r_,p_]:=Graphics@{AbsolutePointSize@1,Point@NestList[#-r#+r RandomChoice@p&,s,n]}

f[10000, {0, 0}, .5, {{-(1/2), Sqrt[3]/2}, {-(1/2), -(Sqrt[3]/2)}, {1, 0}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### How it works

In Mathematica the `Graphics[]` function produces scalable graphics, you render it to whatever size you want by simply dragging the picture corners. In fact, the initial size of all displayed graphics is a ".ini" setting that you may set at 600 or at any other value you wish. So there is no need to do anything special for the 600x600 requirement.

The `AbsolutePointSize[]` thing specifies that the point size will not be modified by enlarging the image size.

The core construct is

```
 NestList[#-r#+r RandomChoice@p&,s,n]
```

or in non-golfed pseudo-code:

```
 NestList[(previous point)*(1-r) + (random vertex point)*(r), (start point), (iterations)]
```

It is recursively building a list starting from `(start point)` and applying the (vectorial) function in the first argument to each successive point, finally returning the list of all calculated points to be plotted by `Point[]`

### Some self-replication examples:

```
Grid@Partition[Table[
   pts = N@{Re@#, Im@#} & /@ Table[E^(2 I Pi r/n), {r, 0, n - 1}];
   Framed@f[10000, {0, 0}, 1/n^(1/n), pts], {n, 3, 11}], 3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @MartinBüttner `Instructions for testing this answer without Mathematica installed:` 1) Download [this](http://pastebin.com/R78mEA2w) from pastebin and save it as *.CDF 2) Download and install the [free CDF environment](http://www.wolfram.com/cdf-player/) from Wolfram Research at  (not a small file). Enjoy. Tell me if it works!

Comment: Your golfed version doesn't quite work (at least on V10): you need to switch around `#r` to `r#` to get away without a space or `*` in between.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Curious! It works like a charm on v9 (I don't have v10 yet). Anyway, I (blindly) swapped the `#` and `r`.

Comment: Ah, it's a new feature. You can now apply functions to associations, in which case you get named parameters that can be accessed by `#key`. I'm sure that will come in handy. :)

Answer (score 9):

## Java : 246 <s>253</s> <s>447</s>

As a function `m()`:

```java
void m(float[]a){new java.awt.Frame(){public void paint(java.awt.Graphics g){int i=0,x=i,y=i,v;for(setSize(832,864),x+=a[1],y+=a[2];i++<=a[0];v=a.length/2-2,v*=Math.random(),x+=(a[v+=v+4]-x)*a[3],y+=(a[v+1]-y)*a[3])g.drawLine(x,y,x,y);}}.show();}
```

Line breaks (within a program to show usage):

```java
class P{
    public static void main(String[]a){
        new P().m(new float[]{1000000,            // iterations
                              416,432,            // start
                              0.6f,               // r
                              416,32,16,432,      // point list...
                              416,832,816,432,
                              366,382,366,482,
                              466,382,466,482});
    }
    
    void m(float[]a){
        new java.awt.Frame(){
            public void paint(java.awt.Graphics g){
                int i=0,x=i,y=i,v;
                for(setSize(832,864),x+=a[1],y+=a[2];
                    i++<=a[0];
                    v=a.length/2-2,v*=Math.random(),
                    x+=(a[v+=v+4]-x)*a[3],
                    y+=(a[v+1]-y)*a[3])
                    g.drawLine(x,y,x,y);
            }
        }.show();
    }
}
```

Drawing input points was removed from the requirements (yay 80 bytes!). They're still shown in the old screenshots below, but won't show up if you run it. See revision history if interested.

The inputs are given as an array of floats. The first is iterations, the next two are starting `x y`. Fourth is `r`, and last comes the list of coordinates, in `x1 y1 x2 y2 ...` fashion.

**Ninja Star**

```java
1000000 400 400 0.6 400 0 0 400 400 800 800 400 350 350 350 450 450 350 450 450
```

[image]

**Cross**

```java
1000000 400 400 0.8 300 0 500 0 500 300 800 300 800 500 500 500 500 800 300 800 300 500 0 500 0 300 300 300
```

[image]

**Octochains**

```java
1000000 400 400 0.75 200 0 600 0 800 200 800 600 600 800 200 800 0 600 0 200
```

[image]

Comment: this does't work in my computer, and java complains `show` is deprecated

Comment: @proudhaskeller `show()` *is* deprecated, but it still works. When you say "doesn't work", what does that mean? If you don't have Java 8, you'll need to add a `final` to `String[]a` in main at least.

Comment: Ported your answer to Processing and cut 100 chars.

Comment: @ace Nice. You can do that with pretty much any Java golf for graphical output, but I like that it's *exactly* 100 chars :D

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript (E6) + Html 173  <s>176 193</s>

Edit: big cut, thanks to William Barbosa

Edit: 3 bytes less, thanks to DocMax

173 bytes counting the function and the canvas element needed to show the output.

**Test** save as html file and open in FireFox.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8nkqxsyd/27/)

[image: Nice]

---

[image: Mask]

---

[image: Snow]

---

[image: Carpet]

---

```javascript
<canvas id=C>
<script>
F=(n,x,y,r,p)=>{
  for(t=C.getContext("2d"),C.width=C.height=600;n--;x-=(x-p[i])*r,y-=(y-p[i+1])*r)
    i=Math.random(t.fillRect(x,y,1,1))*p.length&~1      
}
F(100000, 300, 300, 0.66, [100,500, 500,100, 500,500, 100,100, 300,150, 150,300, 300,450, 450,300]) // Function call, not counted
</script>
```

Comment: `<canvas id=C><script>F=(n,x,y,r,p)=>{t=C.getContext("2d"),C.width=C.height=600;for(;n--;)t.fillRect(x,y,1,1),i=Math.random()*p.length&~1,x-=(x-p[i])*r,y-=(y-p[i+1])*r}</script>` is 176 bytes long, I didn't understand your count

Comment: @WilliamBarbosa my count is right based on my answer. With your hints it gets better - thank you!

Comment: You can shave off two more if you move the size initialization and y update into the `for` call: `for(C.width=C.height=600;n--;y-=(y-p[i+1])*r)`

Answer (score 6):

## Python - <s>200</s> 189

```
import os,random as v
def a(n,s,r,z):
    p=[255]*360000
    for i in[1]*(n+1):
        p[600*s[0]+s[1]]=0;k=v.choice(z);s=[int(k[i]*r+s[i]*(1-r))for i in(0,1)]
    os.write(1,b'P5 600 600 255 '+bytes(p))
```

Takes input as function arguments to a, writes result to stdout as pgm file.
`n` is iterations, `s` is starting point, `r` is r, and `z` is list of input points.

Edit: No longer draws input points in gray.

### Interesting outputs:

[image]

```
Iterations: 100000
Starting Point: (200, 200)
r: 0.8
Points: [(0, 0), (0, 599), (599, 0), (599, 599), (300, 300)]
```

---

[image]

```
Iterations: 100000
Starting Point: (100, 300)
r: 0.6
Points: [(0, 0), (0, 599), (599, 0), (300, 0), (300, 300), (0, 300)]
```

---

[image]

```
Iterations: 100000
Starting Point: (450, 599)
r: 0.75
Points: [(0, 0), (0, 300), (0, 599), (300, 0), (599, 300), (150, 450)]
```

Comment: Some common Python character saves: Initial values like `p=[255]*360000` can go as optional parameters to the function; the body of a for loop can all go on the same line if it has no control flow; you can shave parens from `[1]*(n+1)` as `[1]*-~n`; since you don't use `i` in the outer for loop, it's shorter to run code the `n` times as `exec"code;"*n`); I think the parens in `for i in(0,1)` can be removed.

Answer (score 6):

## Python, <s>189</s> <s>183</s> 175

**Edit:** fixed the inversed *r* ratio, and switched to B&W image in order to save a few bytes.

Takes the number of points as `n`, first point as `p`, ratio as `r` and list of points as `l`.
Needs the module Pillow.

```
import random,PIL.Image as I
s=850
def c(n,p,r,l):
    i=I.new('L',(s,s));x,y=p;
    for j in range(n):w,z=random.choice(l);w*=r;z*=r;x,y=x-x*r+w,y-y*r+z;i.load()[x,s-y]=s
    i.show()
```

Examples:

I am generating points in circle around the image's center

```
points = [(425+s*cos(a)/2, 425+s*sin(a)/2) for a in frange(.0, 2*pi, pi/2)]
c(1000000, (425, 425), 0.4, points)
```

[image]

XOXO repetitions, just changing ratio from 0.4 to 0.6

[image]

Some sort of snow flake

```
stars = [(425+s*cos(a)/2,425+s*sin(a)/2) for a in frange(.0,2*pi, pi/4)]
c(1000000, (425, 425), 0.6, stars)
```

[image]

Comment: Dunno about fixing the backwards _r_ thing, but you can save quite a few characters by making this a program using `n,p,r,l=input()`. You can also remove the brackets from the `*=` operations and use `import random as R`.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Unfortunately, correcting my answer invalidates the optimisation on `*=` :(. The `input` thing would be good be very unpleasant to work with, and the import currently is the most concise form possible (or have I missed something ?).

Comment: I am pretty sure the line can be `import random as R,PIL.Image as I` and then `random.choice` can be `R.choice`. Yeah, using input is lame, but you can use the function version for testing and post the `input()` one for a better score!!1! :P

Comment: Oh, I've just noticed defining random actually saves 0 characters. Oops :S Anyway, I also realized that math is your friend: `y=x*(1-r)+w` == `y=x-x*r-w`.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman that was my point :p. But thanks for the maths.

Answer (score 6):

### SuperCollider - 106

[SuperCollider](http://supercollider.sourceforge.net/) is a language for generating music, but it can do graphics at a pinch.

```
f={|n,p,r,l|Window().front.drawHook_({{Pen.addRect(Rect(x(p=l.choose*(1-r)+(p*r)),p.y,1,1))}!n;Pen.fill})}
```

I've used some obscure syntax shortcuts to save a few bytes - a more readable and more memory-efficient version is

```
f={|n,p,r,l|Window().front.drawHook_({n.do{Pen.addRect(Rect(p.x,p.y,1,1));p=l.choose*(1-r)+(p*r)};Pen.fill})}
```

at 109 chars.

As with the Mathematica example, you have to manually resize the window to get 600x600 pixels. You have to wait for it to re-draw when you do this.

This generates a basic Sierpinsky triangle (not shown because you've seen it before)

```
f.(20000,100@100,0.5,[0@600,600@600,300@0])
```

This makes a kind of Sierpinsky pentagon type thing:

```
f.(100000,100@100,1-(2/(1+sqrt(5))),{|i| (sin(i*2pi/5)+1*300)@(1-cos(i*2pi/5)*300)}!5)
```

[image]

The same thing with 6 points leaves an inverted Koch snowflake in the middle:

```
f.(100000,100@100,1/3,{|i| (sin(i*2pi/6)+1*300)@(1-cos(i*2pi/6)*300)}!6)
```

[image]

Finally, here's a riff on the 3D pyramids from ace's answer. (Note that I've used one of the points twice, to get the shading effect.)

```
f.(150000,100@100,0.49,[300@180, 0@500,0@500,350@400,600@500,250@600])
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript <strike>(407)</strike> (190)

I'm happy to get any feedback on my script and on golfing since I am not comfortable with JS=) (Feel free to use this/change it for your own submission!)

**Reading Input**  (To be comparable to [edc65](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/38201/24877)'s entry I do not count the the input.):

```
p=prompt;n=p();[x,y]=p().split(',');r=p();l=p().split(';').map(e=>e.split(','));
```

**Canvas Setup & Calculation**

```
d=document;d.body.appendChild(c=d.createElement('canvas'));c.width=c.height=1000;c=c.getContext('2d');
for(;n--;c.fillRect(x,y,2,2),[e,f]= l[Math.random()*l.length|0],x-=x*r-e*r,y-=y*r-f*r);
```

Somewhat more ungolfed (including an example input where the real input promts are just commented out, so ready to use):

```
p=prompt;
n=p('n','4000');
[x,y]=p('start','1,1').split(',');
r=p('r','0.5');
l=p('list','1,300;300,1;300,600;600,300').split(';').map(e=>e.split(','));d=document;
d.body.appendChild(c=d.createElement('canvas'));
c.width=c.height=1000;c=c.getContext('2d');
for(;n--;c.fillRect(x,y,2,2),[e,f]= l[Math.random()*l.length|0],x-=x*r-e*r,y-=y*r-f*r);
```

### Examples

```
for(k = 0; k<50; k++){
rad = 10;
l.push([350+rad*k*Math.cos(6.28*k/10),350+rad*k*Math.sin(6.28*k/10)]);
}
r = 1.13;
```

[image]

```
r = 0.5;list = [[1,1],[300,522],[600,1],[300,177]];
```

[image]

```
r = 0.5
list = [[350+350*Math.sin(6.28*1/5),350+350*Math.cos(6.28*1/5)],
[350+350*Math.sin(6.28*2/5),350+350*Math.cos(6.28*2/5)],
[350+350*Math.sin(6.28*3/5),350+350*Math.cos(6.28*3/5)],
[350+350*Math.sin(6.28*4/5),350+350*Math.cos(6.28*4/5)],
[350+350*Math.sin(6.28*5/5),350+350*Math.cos(6.28*5/5)],


[350+90*Math.sin(6.28*1.5/5),350+90*Math.cos(6.28*1.5/5)],
[350+90*Math.sin(6.28*2.5/5),350+90*Math.cos(6.28*2.5/5)],
[350+90*Math.sin(6.28*3.5/5),350+90*Math.cos(6.28*3.5/5)],
[350+90*Math.sin(6.28*4.5/5),350+90*Math.cos(6.28*4.5/5)],
[350+90*Math.sin(6.28*5.5/5),350+90*Math.cos(6.28*5.5/5)]];
```

[image]

Comment: Which ones do you mean?

Comment: Oh thanks for telling me, I am gonna update the submission soon!

Comment: You linked my answer, but I do count the setup of the canvas. I just don't count the single line calling the function. Nice images anyway, espacially the first one.

Comment: Ah I didn't notice that, I just wanted to make it 'comparable', but it's difficult when I try to rely on JS only=) @MartinBüttner Updated, now that I understood it the right way I was able to remove much of the garbage=)

Answer (score 3):

### Processing, 153

Ported @Geobits' Java answer to Processing and did some more golfing, resulting in a reduction of 100 chars. I originally intended to animate the process, but the input constraints are too harsh on this (Processing does not have stdin or argv, which means that I must write my own function instead of using Processing's native `draw()` loop).

```java
void d(float[]a){int v;size(600,600);for(float i=0,x=a[1],y=a[2];i++<a[0];v=(int)random(a.length/2-2),point(x+=(a[v*2+4]-x)*a[3],y+=(a[v*2+5]-y)*a[3]));}
```

Complete program with line breaks:

```java
void setup() {
  d(new float[]{100000,300,300,.7,0,600,600,0,600,600,0,0,400,400,200,200,400,200,200,400}); 
}
void d(float[]a){
  int v;
  size(600,600);
  for(float i=0,x=a[1],y=a[2];
      i++<a[0];
      v=(int)random(a.length/2-2),point(x+=(a[v*2+4]-x)*a[3],y+=(a[v*2+5]-y)*a[3]));
}
```

Above program gives Crosses:
[image]

```java
d(new float[]{100000,300,300,.65,142,257,112,358,256,512,216,36,547,234,180,360});
```

This gives Pyramids:
[image]

```java
d(new float[]{100000,100,500,.5,100,300,500,100,500,500});
```

This gives Sierpinski triangle:
[image]

Comment: I love the 3D effect of the pyramids. :)

Answer (score 1):

### Ungolfed "reference implementation", Python

**Update**: much, much faster (by orders of magnitude)

**Check out the interactive shell!**

Edit the file and set `interactive` to `True`, then do one of these:

`polygon numberOfPoints numeratorOfWeight denominatorOfWeight startX startY numberOfSides` generates, saves and displays a polygon.

`points numberOfPoints numeratorOfWeight denominatorOfWeight startX startY point1X point1Y point2X point2Y ...` does what the spec asks for.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from fractions import Fraction as F
import random
from matplotlib.colors import ColorConverter
from time import sleep
import math
import sys
import cmd
import time

def plot_saved(n, r, start, points, filetype='png', barsize=30, dpi=100, poly=True, show=False):
    printed_len = 0

    plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
    plt.axis('off')

    start_time = time.clock()
    f = F.from_float(r).limit_denominator()

    spts = []
    for i in range(len(points)):
        spts.append(tuple([round(points[i].real,1), round(points[i].imag,1)]))

    if poly:
        s = "{}-gon ({}, r = {}|{})".format(len(points), n, f.numerator, f.denominator)
    else:
        s = "{} ({}, r = {}|{})".format(spts, n, f.numerator, f.denominator) 

    step = math.floor(n / 50)

    for i in range(len(points)):
        plt.scatter(points[i].real, points[i].imag, color='#ff2222', s=50, alpha=0.7)

    point = start
    t = time.clock()

    xs = []
    ys = []

    for i in range(n+1):
        elapsed = time.clock() - t
        #Extrapolation
        eta = (n+1-i)*(elapsed/(i+1))
        printed_len = rewrite("{:>29}: {} of {} ({:.3f}%) ETA: {:.3f}s".format(
                s, i, n, i*100/n, eta), printed_len)
        xs.append(point.real)
        ys.append(point.imag)
        point = point * r + random.choice(points) * (1 - r)

    printed_len = rewrite("{:>29}: plotting...".format(s), printed_len)
    plt.scatter(xs, ys, s=0.5, marker=',', alpha=0.3)

    presave = time.clock()
    printed_len = rewrite("{:>29}: saving...".format(s), printed_len)
    plt.savefig(s + "." + filetype, bbox_inches='tight', dpi=dpi)

    postsave = time.clock()
    printed_len = rewrite("{:>29}: done in {:.3f}s (save took {:.3f}s)".format(
                            s, postsave - start_time, postsave - presave),
                            printed_len)

    if show:
        plt.show()
    print()
    plt.clf()

def rewrite(s, prev):
    spaces = prev - len(s)
    sys.stdout.write('\r')
    sys.stdout.write(s + ' '*(0 if spaces < 0 else spaces))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    return len(s)

class InteractiveChaosGame(cmd.Cmd):
    def do_polygon(self, args):
        (n, num, den, sx, sy, deg) = map(int, args.split())
        plot_saved(n, (num + 0.0)/den, np.complex(sx, sy), list(np.roots([1] + [0]*(deg - 1) + [-1])), show=True)

    def do_points(self, args):
        l = list(map(int, args.split()))
        (n, num, den, sx, sy) = tuple(l[:5])
        l = l[5:]
        points = []
        for i in range(len(l)//2):
            points.append(complex(*tuple([l[2*i], l[2*i + 1]])))
        plot_saved(n, (num + 0.0)/den, np.complex(sx, sy), points, poly=False, show=True)

    def do_pointsdpi(self, args):
        l = list(map(int, args.split()))
        (dpi, n, num, den, sx, sy) = tuple(l[:6])
        l = l[6:]
        points = []
        for i in range(len(l)//2):
            points.append(complex(*tuple([l[2*i], l[2*i + 1]])))
        plot_saved(n, (num + 0.0)/den, np.complex(sx, sy), points, poly=False, show=True, dpi=dpi)

    def do_default(self, args):
        do_generate(self, args)

    def do_EOF(self):
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    interactive = False
    if interactive:
        i = InteractiveChaosGame()
        i.prompt = ": "
        i.completekey='tab'
        i.cmdloop()
    else:
        rs = [1/2, 1/3, 2/3, 3/8, 5/8, 5/6, 9/10]
        for i in range(3, 15):
            for r in rs:
                plot_saved(20000, r, np.complex(0,0), 
                            list(np.roots([1] + [0] * (i - 1) + [-1])), 
                            filetype='png', dpi=300)
```

Comment: Without running this, I have no idea what *awesome* means. Perhaps you could explain, or show some pictures of what makes it different from the shorter ones?

Comment: @Geobits edited to include disclaimer and picture :)

Comment: I'd prefer if you included this under a separate heading (e.g. Ungolfed Reference Implementation) in your other answer as posting *only* ungolfed code is technically "not an answer".

Answer (score -2):

### Python (202 chars)

Takes the number of points as `n`, the averaging weight as `r`, the starting point as a `tuple` `s` and the list of points as a list of XY `tuple`s called `l`.

```
import random as v,matplotlib.pyplot as p
def t(n,r,s,l):
 q=complex;s=q(*s);l=[q(*i)for i in l];p.figure(figsize=(6,6))
 for i in range(n):p.scatter(s.real,s.imag,s=1,marker=',');s=s*r+v.choice(l)*(1-r)
 p.show()
```

Comment: @MartinBüttner Does the fact that I'm taking a specific type of input meet the spec?

Comment: Also, on my machine, the result is not 600x600 pixels, x and y have different length scales and the points cover more than 1 pixel.